# I have an issue with onCreate function of Cloud functions for Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im not able to change a field value on creating them.
My collection structure:
 Orders/{OrderId}:

{"description" : "some description",
   "status" : ""
  }

All i need to update the 'status' field with status as 'CREATED'.
But some how im not able to figure it out. Can you guys please help me out.

My index.ts file:

'''

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp()

export const onOrderCreate = functions.firestore 
   .document('order/{orderId}')
   .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    if (snapshot.exists) {
        const data =  snapshot.id;
        const id = data;
        console.log(context.params);
        return await admin.firestore().collection('orders').doc(id)
        .update({status : 'CREATED'}).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
            return;
          });
    }
    else {
        console.log('Returned null')
        return null
    }
  })
```

'''

Expected output should be:
Orders/{OrderId}:

{"description" : "some description",
   "status" : "CREATED"
  }

Comment: You mentioned your collection is called `Orders` but in the code snippet the function trigger works on `order` collection. Also, what is the result or error? Do you see function invocations in the function log?

Comment: Thats a blunder from my side. Thanks @DougStevenson for your response. Its working fine now.